# In Xcode run-script how can I pring the real value from plist edited by xcconfig

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, run-script, xcconfig

I have my normal project and the default plist file, and I also created a xcconfig file.

First I added one key-value in my plist whose key is called `custom_mode` and value is connected to the value in xcconfig file like this:

```
//In .plist file
<dict>
    <key>custom_mode</key>
    <string>$(xcconfig_mode)</string>
</dict>
```

Second, in my xcconfig file it is set like this:

```
//In .xcconfig file
xconfig_mode = debugMode
```

Last I created one script trying to fetch and print the value like this:

```
//In .script file
script_mode=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print custom_mode' "${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
echo "plist value for custom_mode: ${custom_mode}"
```

When I finished the above steps and run the app, the script is printing but only it is like

```
"plist value for custom_mode: $(xcconfig_mode)"
```

It didn't print the real value set by xcconfig file but the variable name. So how can I be able to get the real value set by xcconfig?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running this script in a build phase script here the build settings are available as environment variables when you can use this:

```
script_mode_var=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print custom_mode' "${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
script_mode=${!script_mode_var}
```

From man bash:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it
>   introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the
>   variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.

An alternative way is to take the value from the info.plist that Xcode has already processed(and replaced the variables with their value). This can be found in the path plist="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH". So you can modify you script as such:

```
plist="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
script_mode=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print custom_mode' "${plist}")
```